# Non-convex quadrilateral and pentagon?

Tags: problem-solving

Is it possible to draw a non-convex quadrilateral/pentagon and an additional straight line such that the straight line cuts through the interior of each of the quadrilateral/pentagon's edges?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: One of them is quite easy to do if you experiment a little. For the other notice that as you travel around the polygon, you'll cross the extra line once for each side of the polygon, and you have to end up on the same side of it from which you started.